# How to align an image-view for all android screens

Tags: android, imageview, alignment

I want to align an image view which is displayed same for all android screens expect for Android tab screen. Different alignment of imageview is noticed for imageview when app runs on emulator or live device. how do i align them properly??

**Here is my activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#fff" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/forts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/forts" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/portal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/forts"
    android:layout_below="@+id/forts"
    android:src="@drawable/portal" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emergency"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/forts"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/portal"
    android:src="@drawable/emergency" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/aboutus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/portal"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/emergency"
    android:src="@drawable/aboutus" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/maps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/emergency"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emergency"
    android:src="@drawable/maps" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mailus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emergency"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/aboutus"
    android:src="@drawable/mailus" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use drawable folder and dimen folder for placing diffrent images mdpi,hdpi,ldpi,xhdpi etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have set variable dimen in different values folder as

```
1:values    
    -dimens.xml    
     <dimen name="image_email_width">45dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="image_email_height">35dp</dimen>

2:values-xlarge
-dimens.xml   

     <dimen name="image_email_width">90dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="image_email_height">70dp</dimen>
```

Then set your Imageview as

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/portal"
    android:layout_width="@dimens/image_email_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimens/image_email_height"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/forts"
    android:layout_below="@+id/forts"
    android:src="@drawable/portal" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different types of images i.e. ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi.

Answer (score 1):

For different screen size and different densities image will differ.
For fitting the image into imageview usee,

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

If you want your imageview similar to all devices, you need to create different layout folders for different screen sizes and different images like ldpi,hdpi,mdpi for different densities.